# Java - Returning an "address" from an ArrayList of names and addresses

Tags: java, arraylist

I've been working on this AP Problem all day with no luck. If anyone can help, it would be appreciated.

I have an `ArrayList` of `Strings` composed of names and addresses. After the addresses, there is an empty `String` and the next name starts. The method `getAddress` takes a String parameter (a name) and returns the address of the pereson (the lines after the name including the empty String, but stopping there). I'm having trouble writing this method.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Recipients {
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    public String extractCity(String cityZip) {
        int pos = cityZip.indexOf(",");
        return cityZip.substring(0, pos);
    }
    public void printNames() {
        System.out.println(lines.get(0));
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.size()-1; i++) 
            if (lines.get(i).substring(0, lines.get(i).length()).equals("")) 
                System.out.println(lines.get(i+1));
    }
    public String getAddress(String name) {
        String address = "";
        int ct = 0;
        int place = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
            if (lines.get(i).substring(0, lines.get(i).length()).equals(name)) {
                place = i;
                for (int j = i+1; j < lines.size(); j++) {
                    ct = j;
                    if (!lines.get(i).substring(0, lines.get(i).length()).equals("")) {
                        ct++;
                    }
                }
                for (int k = place; k < ct; k++) {
                    address = address + lines.get(i);
                }
            }
        }

        return address;
    }
        public void main() {
            lines.add("Mr. J Adams");
            lines.add("Rose St.");
            lines.add("Ithaca, NY 14850");
            lines.add("");
            lines.add("Jack S. Smith");
            lines.add("12 Posy Way");
            lines.add("Suite #201");
            lines.add("Glendale, CA 91203");
            lines.add("");
            lines.add("Ms. M.K. Delgado");
            lines.add("2 River Dr.");
            lines.add("");
            System.out.println(getAddress("Jack S. Smith"));
            System.out.println("test line break");
            }
}
```

Thank you for your time.

EDIT: This method is supposed to be written in the Recipients class. It has an assumed constructor and I've written other methods inside the class. I've edited the class. I'm having trouble with the logic.

Worksheet says: Write the getAddress method of the Recipients class. This method should return a string that contains only the address of the corresponding name parameter. For example, if name is "Jack S. Smith", a string containing the three subsequent lines of his address should be returned. This string should contain line breaks in appropriate places, including after the last line of the address.

```
public String getAddress(String name)
```

Comment: I suggest creating a class which holds each field separately.

Comment: Also, does this code compile and run? I see that you have a function named `main()`, but it is not correct if you want to use it as the entry point of your code.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice He's trying to show a minimal example of his code.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (;

Comment: @NickZiebert I am very aware of what an MCVE is. If you look at the comment history in my profile, you will see how often I ask for one.

Comment: Yeah, I was being a smart alec.  Some of you guys always find some way to complain (;

Comment: @NickZiebert The Internet tends to drop sarcasm packets on a regular basis.

Comment: I am sorry, Stack Overflow isn’t really a good place for questions as open as “I'm having trouble writing this method.”

Comment: If you *must* use data on this list format: I think I’d exit the first loop as soon as I had found the name. Then exit the second loop as soon as I had found the empty line. Then you should know the start and end indices of the address. First I’d consider a different data model, though, but this has been said already.

Comment: @OleV.V. as you proceed to answer.

Comment: @Rizwan M.Tuman's answer was correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to use as you have wanted then you need to modify your getAddress method. Try the following getAddress method in your code:

```
public String getAddress(String name) {
    String address = "";
    boolean nameFound=false;
    for(String str:lines)
    {
        if(!nameFound && str.equals(name))
            nameFound=true;
        else if(nameFound && str.isEmpty())
            break;
        else if(nameFound && !str.isEmpty())
            address+=str;
    }
    return address;
}
```

Comment: Glad to know that it helped!

Answer (score 2):

You should create class for saving name and address. Please find below mentioned approach.

```
package hello;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Employee {

    private String name;
    private String address;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

}

public class So3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        lines.add("Mr. J Adams");
        lines.add("Rose St.");
        lines.add("Ithaca, NY 14850");
        lines.add("");
        lines.add("Jack S. Smith");
        lines.add("12 Posy Way");
        lines.add("Suite #201");
        lines.add("Glendale, CA 91203");
        lines.add("");
        lines.add("Ms. M.K. Delgado");
        lines.add("2 River Dr.");
        lines.add("");

        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        for (String str : lines) {
            if (str.isEmpty()) {
                if (employee.getName() != null && employee.getAddress() != null) {
                    employees.add(employee);
                    employee = new Employee();
                }
            } else if (employee.getName() == null) {
                employee.setName(str);
            } else {
                if (employee.getAddress() == null) {
                    employee.setAddress(str);
                } else {
                    employee.setAddress(employee.getAddress() + " " + str);
                }
            }
        }

        if (employee.getName() != null && employee.getAddress() != null) {
            employees.add(employee);
        }

        System.out.println(getAddress(employees, "Ms. M.K. Delgado"));

    }

    private static String getAddress(List<Employee> employees, String name) {
        if (employees != null && name != null) {
            for (Employee employee : employees) {
                if (name.equals(employee.getName())) {
                    return employee.getAddress();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use HashMap rather than an ArrayList for this.  This is a perfect scenario to use HashMap instead.

```
public class APProblem {
    Map<String, List<String>> lines2 = new HashMap<>();

    public List<String> getAddress(String name) {
        return lines2.get(name);
    }

        public void main() {
            String name = "Mr. J Adams";
            List<String> address = Arrays.asList("Rose St.", "Ithaca, NY 14850");
            lines2.put(name, address);
            name = "Jack S. Smith";
            address = Arrays.asList("12 Posy Way", "Suite #201", "Glendale, CA 91203");
            lines2.put(name, address);

            System.out.println(getAddress("Jack S. Smith"));
            System.out.println("Testing line break.");
            }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `Map<String, List<String>>`, use `Map<String, Address>` where `Address` is a custom class.

Comment: Not sure what the purpose of a map would be if he were to create a Address class.

Comment: An `Address` class serves the same purpose as your `List<String>` but more clearly.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just have a "name" field variable in your Address class?  Are you complaining again? (;

Comment: Of course, you can have a name in the Address class as well. How would you then store a bunch of Address objects?

Comment: So many good comments on a bad answer makes me wonder why there is only one downvote.

Comment: @GhostCat why is my answer bad?

Comment: It starts with the fact that a map is for sure not the perfect data structure to use here. The answer from cody nailed it, your answer only adds to confusion of the OP who considers flat strings to be good representation of such data.

Comment: @GhostCat As a long time SO user, I'm sure you're aware that you cannot always point out every problem in somebody's code.  And, who knows, maybe this user is at the beginning of their AP class and they haven't talked about classes yet.  I agree, this is not an OO solution, but I try to answer the question at hand without making too many assumptions.  I guess I could add a note at the end about this not being a good OO approach.  I also see you didn't downvote the other answer that doesn't talk about the use of another class.  Makes me wonder why...

Comment: The main reason for my downvote is your statement that using a hashmap is *perfect* here. That is simply wrong. The perfect solution looks much different. So instead of defending yourself, consider editing your answer. Sometimes it is just a bit of wording that makes the difference.

Comment: So you think there is only **one** "Jack S. Smith" in the world? Or what is your perfect solution doing when there are two persons with the same name and a different address? But sure, if you think it is perfect as it is; then we both have to live with that.

Comment: You do realize this is a homework assignment for a high schooler right?  I never said my solution was perfect, I said the use of hashmap instead of arraylist is perfect.  Go downvote the other two since they didn't take this into account either.  Your killin me man...

Comment: You really don't get it? If you had spent 10 seconds to change your sentence to something like "an alternative to using a list could be the usage of a hashmap which has this and that advantage; and this and that drawback" ... and the downvote would long have been revered. But nope, you keep arguing why your mediocre wording is perfect.